# Using Visual Studio and Windows Forms (C#) to upload and rename file to network drive

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's some code I'm working on:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
                Title = "Add a PDF",

                CheckFileExists = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,

                DefaultExt = "pdf",
                Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf",
                FilterIndex = 2,
                RestoreDirectory = true,

                ReadOnlyChecked = true,
                ShowReadOnly = true
            };

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string myFile = textBox1.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(myFile);

            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(myFile, @"C:\testing\records\file.pdf");
    }
}
```

}

So anyway toward the bottom at button2, I'm trying to set up a few things. I want to add a button that saves the file using the System.IO line there. But when I add the button, I can't get it to work properly. The "myFile" variable doesn't seem to be declared anymore. I'm sure this is probably the messiest code anyone will paste on here today, but a lot of it was auto-genned by Visual Studio and I'm afraid to clean it up because I'm not 100% sure what some of this stuff is. I have tried cutting and pasting the button stuff up nearer to the myFile variable declaration since it's private and maybe that's why it doesn't know what it means anymore. But when I move it up there, I get a different error regarding the "private" at the beginning of the button call.

Comment: Is your question just "Is it possible?"...? Many things are possible in programming. You should actually *try* it. This site isn't really meant for hypothetical questions.

Comment: I am trying it. I'm running into a lot of snags and I can't seem to figure out how to do it on my own. I've made a couple of forms with Visual Studio and I'm not having any luck on this one.

Comment: Then it's perfectly acceptable to ask questions about the specific snags you're running into. This question is broad and not really answerable beyond a "yes". You might want to read the topics on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page for ideas of what a good question is.

Comment: Okay, I've revised my question to be much more specific. I hope this is more acceptable.

Comment: Honestly, your best bet would be to just delete and post as a new question. This was already downvoted 5 times and you essentially changed the entire question after an hour. You aren't going to get those votes back.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that too. But since I'm so new, I have to wait 5 days before posting again. Thank you for your recommendations. I'll just keep googling or seeing about signing up for a similar website to get this question posted there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're declaring your myFile variable within the scope of the if statement and so when that if statement block exits the myFile variable goes out of scope and no longer exists.

To get it to work you need to move the creation of the myFile variable to the class level.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private string myFile;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Other code snipped out
}
```

Now modify your button1_Click code so that instead of creating an instance of myFile:

```
string myFile = textBox1.Text;
```

You just populate the private variable you declared in the main part of the code:

```
myFile = textBox1.Text;
```

So the `if` statement looks like this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    myFile = textBox1.Text;
    Console.WriteLine(myFile);
}
```

You need a little modification to button2_Click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check that myFile has some text and isn't null.
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(myFile))
        return;

    // Check that the file exists before attempting to move it.
    if (File.Exists(myFile))
        System.IO.File.Move(myFile, @"C:\testing\records\file.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The only issue I'm still seeing is this line:

 if (File.Exists(myFile))
        System.IO.File.Move(myFile, @"C:\testing\records\file.pdf");

The first "File" in there is throwing an error. MVS is saying "The name "File" does not exist in the current context".

Comment: `File.Exists` is in the `System.IO` namespace, so you can either pre-qualify by putting `System.IO.File.Exists(myFile);` or by putting `using System.IO;` at the top of the code file along with the other using lines.

Comment: For a program like this where it's primarily for file manipulation, I probably wanna just put the System.IO at the top. eh? Considering how much file moving and checking I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it saves you having to type out the entire namespace all the time.